# ResponsiveGridLayout static items leave HUGE gap (unusable)

Tags: react-grid-layout

Not sure what to do, has anyone run into this?

When grid items are static, it leaves a BIG gap before the items:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dawn-cww14

When grid items are NOT static, everything seems fine:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dhawan-2xs1l

Comment: You might be better off raising an issue in the package's repo - just a suggestion.

Comment: @PowellYe Thanks for the suggestion, I did but they are very slow at responding. Saw the tag so thought people might have run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `isDraggable`, `isRearrangeable`, and `isResizable` seems to fix it. But there is still a bug. I noted it [here](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/958).

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
    className="pageGraphs"
    breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
    cols={{ lg: 2, md: 2, sm: 2, xs: 1, xxs: 1 }}
    isDraggable={false}
    isRearrangeable={false}
    isResizable={false}
    style={{}}
>
```